# What's my mistake with "strpos" function?

Tags: php, strpos

I am trying to get `strpos` to search string variable `$string` for the phrase "test" and if it doesn't contain "test" another variable `$change` is redefined as `$string2` (where `$change` has been defined previously)

```
if (strpos($string, 'test') == false) {
    $change = $string2;
    break;
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

What is the mistake in the code above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about strpos in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004897/question-about-strpos-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

strpos returns false if it does not find the string, which is equivalent to 0 in a type-unspecific conditional in PHP.  Make sure to use the === operator when comparing using strpos.

```
if (strpos($string, 'test') === false) {
  $change = $string2;
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
if (strpos($string, 'test') === false)

=== instead of ==
```

Answer (score 3):

`strpos` can return "false" or can return "0" which can be misread as false, so instead of using the `==` comparison operator (which means "equal to") you have to use `===` (which means identical to). You might also consider a ternary statement instead of a break:

```
  $change = (strpos($string, 'test') === false) ? $string2 : $change;
```