# PHP Strpos can't find first character?

Tags: php, html

I am getting an array, and I filter it to get just the text, in the text I am looking for something like "20/" Making sure the 20/ exist then if it does, it will go to another part of the code BUT I can't seem to figure out how to get it recognized if its a 1-9/ to 20/.

```
if ($spot = strpos($dir[$x]->output, '9/')) {
echo "Valid";
} 

else {
gotto2();
}
```

So, it doesn't ever find it, but if I remove the number, it'll find the "/".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about strpos in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004897/question-about-strpos-in-php)

Comment: Sadly that didn't work either :\. Thank you though. It says not found in his code.

Comment: no the OP is doing assignment in the if condition, singe ( = )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your if condition is all wrong.

try this,

```
if (false !== strpos($dir[$x]->output, '9/')) {
    echo "Valid";
}
```

your doing assignment to $spot ( single = ) even a double == is not suffencient to check because if the position is 0, you need to check for Boolean false strictly ( or in this case true, but we dont care about the position so valid is 0 to any pos ) and we cant look for boolen true , so we check for anything but boolean false

if this doen't work you will have to post the input string as well.

Comment: This is so right, I wish I could upvote this but I made it the right answer. You ARE an artistic Phoenix, in all its glory. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, easy one to spot, glad I could point you in the right direction.  It would always evaluate as true with assignment.